# Redirect www to non www https in IIS in elastic beanstalk

Tags: .net, redirect, iis, web-config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following redirect rule which redirects all the http requests to https.

```
 <rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I want this rule to redirect all `www` traffic to `non www https`as well.
The application is deployed to a Load balanced EBS enviornment.

Let me know if any other information is needed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I added another rule to `web.config` file. Below is the code

```
<rule name="Remove www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```